# Laravel 5- how to process csv file?

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I have Excel file like below.

[image]

I export it to csv. It looks like below.

[image]

I would like to display the content like below but not in excel but in html table.

[image]

```
public function numbers()
{
    $filepath = base_path('/storage/app/test5.csv');
    $file = file($filepath);
    $cols = explode(';', $file[0]);
    unset($cols[0]);
    $cols = array_values($cols);
    $vars = [];
    $values = [];
    foreach ($file as $k => $line) {
        if ($k > 0) {
            $row = explode(';', $line);
            foreach ($row as $i => $cell) {
                if ($i == 0) {
                    $vars[] = $row[0];
                } else {
                    $values['var' . $k]['col' . $i] = $row[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return view('layouts.liczby', ['cols' => $cols, 'vars' => $vars, 'values' => $values]);
}
```

My view looks like that

```
<table>
@foreach($vars as $v) 
   @foreach ($cols as $c)
<tr>
    <td>{{$v}}</td>
    <td>{{$c}}</td>
    <td>{{$values[$v][$c]}}</td>
</tr>
   @endforeach 
@endforeach

</table>
```

I get an error - **Undefined index: col3** Please help.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you https://murze.be/processing-a-csv-file-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) is a build in php function that will convert a csv string to an array.
You should not parse this data yourself.

Comment: Glad I could help, considder marking this as the answer so other users might also find this.